LanguageTool stopped working after TeXstudio update
(Running TeXstudio 4.8.4 on Apple M2 with macOS Sequoia 15.1)
A few months ago, LanguageTool stopped working after I updated TeXstudio. I didn't bother fixing it then, but now that I am using it heavily, I intend to fix it and have it working again.
Here is the relevant info:

which java outputs /usr/bin/java.

which languagetool-server outputs /opt/homebrew/bin/languagetool-server.

My current LanguageTool settings (which have been tinkered with (in the hopes of fixing it) since when LanguageTool was working fine before the update) are as follows:


In TeXstudio, Help > Check LanguagTool outputs the following LT Report.txt:


which java: /usr/bin/java


JAVA: /usr/bin/java
process crashed

Real-time checking is enabled.
Grammar checking is enabled.

Tries to start automatically.

LT current status: working

LT-URL: http://localhost:8081/v2/check

(I guess process crashed is indicating trouble.)

The http://localhost:8081/v2/check in a browser shows Error: Missing 'text' or 'data' parameter, which also doesn't sound alright.

Question/Request: Can someone please help me getting my LanguageTool up and atom again?
